# How to dedupe/merge contacts from different sources?

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, google, office-365

I have Google Contacts and Office 365 People both on my iPhone/iPad. Whenever a contact is both on Google and Office, they will appear as two different persons in my iOS Contacts app. If I want to update any information about the contact, it appears that I'll have to do that twice.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Ideally, I'd like to have ALL my contacts on Google Contacts, and merely SOME of them on Office 365 People. I'd like the latter to be in sync with the former. I'd love them to show just a single card per person in iOS Contacts.

Comment: I just have a question: If you create a contact in the Contacts app rather than in google or O365 do both Google and O365 see it?

Comment: @PaulGilfedder That's interesting. I just added you in the Contacts app. You then showed up in O365, but not (yet?) on Google. (More problems!)

Comment: @PaulGilfedder There is a setting for the Contacts default account. It was pointing to O365. "New contacts created outside of a specific account will be added to this account."

Comment: Next step I suppose is set Google as the default account and see what happens. Seeing as you want Google to be your master contacts list

Comment: @PaulGilfedder I did and added your brother. He immediately popped up in Google and not on O365. Well, that is certainly good to know and helpful. Thanks. But now suppose I want your brother also in O365? Do I really have to maintain duplicates?

Comment: The closest fix I could do is drag a contact from one address book to another. I created one in the local contacts and dragged it to google and it updated. Its a single create and then a drag not perfect but at the moment its as close as I can get

Comment: @PaulGilfedder I think I figured it out. In Contacts you can edit a contact and link it to other contacts. They then become one. I'll have a look if it will sync all ways. Thanks for putting me on this track. (Did you?) ... OK, it still doesn't really sync. :( But at least they are together now.

Comment: I think the answer was all your own work. I just asked if eth contacts app could boss the other systems around. :)

Comment: @PaulGilfedder When you said 'dragged it to google', this was not on an iPad/iPhone, or was it? If so, how did you do that?

Comment: My goof sorry -- I had started to test in the Mac desktop trying a few things from there to see if I could see the same things happening

Answer (score 1):

Merely partially answering my own question:

First make sure to have `Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > CONTACTS > Default Account` set to `Gmail`.

Cards from Office 365 and Google that are of the same person can be edited in iOS Contacts. Edit one contact and, right at the bottom (remove the keyboard) one finds `link contacts...`. There select the other card. (Press `link` **just once**.)

This will put all information of that person in one card in iOS Contacts. However, it doesn't seem to push any information from Office 365 to Google or vice versa. If anyone knows how to do that, please let me know.